# javascript code to get 2 js files and then,after comparing,return the appropriate variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

i m building an app in appery.io.and i have some problems.the guys there told me to
use server code.

So the workflow of the Server code will be:

1. Get JS file from the source.  (http://ekloges-prev.singularlogic.eu/v2012b/stat/statics.js)
2. Get other JS file from the other source. (http://ekloges-prev.singularlogic.eu/v2012b/dyn/ep_38.js)
3. Iterate through the first JS file object and set "name" for each needed item.(you can get it from 2nd js file).
4. Return single response(that will contain all needed information).
5. Then you can use this server code to get response with all need information.

These 2 files contain the field "id" which is common.the 1st file,also includes a "party" which actually is the party_name.so what i want is the code to send the id to the first file,search for the appropriate party name,and return it to my field!what could i do??

Comment: Your question is way to broad. You have to try something and explain exactly what you're having difficulty with.

Comment: sorry for that!in this app i m using this get service 
http://imageshack.com/a/img631/9677/LWuYi5.jpg 
and i m taking some results from the 1st file http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img538/1646/1UeEPK.jpg such as party_id..then,i just want to "add" the party_name,contained in this file 
http://ekloges-prev.singularlogic.eu/v2012b/stat/statics.js .
how can i compare the 2 js files by id and get the party_name as a result??and the second problem is that this file is a static one.so when i try to create the get service,i get this error!
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img538/5180/ENZmpx.jpg

Comment: sorry to ask,but honestly i m so confused..i tried about a million things,but nothing seems to work...

Comment: @Konstantions Then show the code you've tried, actual behavior, expected behavior and any error messages

Comment: ok!since i m in a platform,i didnt use server code,but i tried to use the tools of the platform!so firstly i created the rest service to get data from the first file.it was succesfull.then i tried to create a get service for this file: http://ekloges-prev.singularlogic.eu/v2012b/stat/statics.js
it returned this error: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img538/5180/ENZmpx.jpg so at first i want help on how to create a restful service for this file so i can get data!

Comment: just to be completely honest,i was trying to avoid js code,because i m a dummy in javascript programming..but as it seems,js is the only way to do it..thats why i m trying to find how to do it!

Comment: @Konstantions Sorry man, I don't understand what you're asking. Stack Overflow is intended for code questions like: "Here's my code, it should do A but it does B, how can I fix it?" Here's one thing that noticed: One file returns JSON and the other returns JavaScript, so you have to treat them differently. If you were using HTML/JavaScript, you can use a script tag to call  http://ekloges-prev.singularlogic.eu/v2012b/stat/statics.js and `window.static` would contain your object. For the other file, it's JSON, so you'd need an AJAX call like http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: The same applies if you're doing this on the server, you have to treat both URLs differently